# Laptop won't boot or enter BIOS after deleting partition in Windows 7

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-7, delete, bios

I dual boot my computer and later decided to delete one of the Ubuntu partitions while using Windows 7. After my computer hibernated and I tried restarting my ASUS laptop it stopped at the logo and preventing me from entering the BIOS. When I take out my hard dive it allows me to enter the BIOS. It does not boot from a CD if the hard drive is still attached to the computer. After taking the hard drive out then it boots from the CD.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please I need help

Comment: It's more likely a hardware problem.  With the drive plugged in does it eventually give an error or do anything else.  To boot off the CD while the HDD is plugged in you will have to change the boot order.  You should try resetting the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) (start where it says "restoring MBR") but instead, first remove the hard drive before booting into the CD. Once your computer has booted onto the CD then re-insert the hard drive and follow the steps outlines. I have no way of confirming this works, I just think it might (I've never heard of anything like this before).